# RabbitMQ: Limit workers on specific routing key

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging

I am using RabbitMQ java API, I got a workers that are registered for `*.apple` routing key. I want to make sure that no more then one worker will work on explicated routing key.

For example, given to the queue 3 jobs:

- orange.apple
- green.apple
- orange.apple

Two workers will start immediately on `orange.apple` and `green.apple`, and only after acknowledgment on `orange.apple` a new `orange.apple` worker will start.

Answer (score 0):

you can't limit anything based on routing keys, other than the queue to which a message is delivered.

in your situation, you want to limit the worker by queue, and you can achieve this by setting the consumer to be "exclusive" when it connects to / consumes from the queue.

you will probably want to use consumer pre-fetch limit of 1, and "auto ack" of false, as well.

this way you will have a single consumer on a queue, it will only process one message at a time, and you will be required to ack the message when you're done working on it, before you get the next message.

Comment: So how do I limit the worker by queue and make orange and green to run simultaneously?

Comment: one queue per message type. you have an "orange.apple" queue, and a "green.apple" queue. each has their own consumer with the configuration, above

Comment: The problem is that I need a wild card "*.apple" and only when its exact same routing key, I want to limit the queue.